# Extracting a substring before a multiple and regular expression pattern

Tags: r

In to need to get a substring from the following elements of a R data frame column. In detail, I need to take the substring located before the first number or the first open brachet ('['). Even the trailing space should be removed.

```
   [1] "Arturo Beniamo 29 10 2015.docx"               
   [2] "Arturo Beniamo [30 12 2015].docx"               
   [3] "Dominici Leonardo 02 06 2019.docx"                
   [4] "Didonna Marco 07 09 2023.docx"
```

This should be the result:

```
   [1] "Arturo Beniamo"               
   [2] "Arturo Beniamo"               
   [3] "Dominici Leonardo"                
   [4] "Didonna Marco"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use :

```
x <- c("Arturo Beniamo 29 10 2015.docx", "Arturo Beniamo [30 12 2015].docx" , 
       "Dominici Leonardo 02 06 2019.docx", "Didonna Marco 07 09 2023.docx")

sub('\\s(\\d|\\[).*', '', x)
#[1] "Arturo Beniamo"    "Arturo Beniamo"   "Dominici Leonardo" "Didonna Marco"
```

This removes a whitespace (`\\s`) followed by either a number (`\\d`) or an opening square bracket (`[`).